# PHP exec operator doesn't execute specific command

Tags: php, process, permissions, exec, shell-exec

One of my lines of shell command is not executing despite other similar lines working. I am running on a linux machine using a Ubuntu 12.04 based OS. I have tried using exec as well, still doesn't work.

I actually had this working at some point, where I ran into the hanging issue (waiting for command output), which is why I'm redirecting output to /dev/null. So some where in the development something changed. We did create a debian package to install with and I had run that install package so I thought maybe in overwriting a file the permissions got changed so I added read/write/execute to all users/groups/owners but that didn't work either.

The code is here:

```
if(isset($_POST['activateXML']))
{
    if (videoConsistencyCheck())
    {
        `cp {$fileXML} /apps/video/xml.xml`;
        `sudo /apps/video/vsss restart >/dev/null 2>&1 &`;
        systemUnvalidate();
        header('Location: index.php?app='.$_GET['app']);
        die();
    }
}
```

I know that the first line in the if statement gets executed. The line of code works fine in the actually terminal, so that isn't the problem either. I did lots of Googling and all I could find is an unanswered question, any advice would be helpful.

EDIT: so what appeared to be not working was in fact calling the command as intended but in the bash script I was calling the start-stop daemon was not working

EDIT 2: I made a test php file and ran the code from the terminal, fixed the start-stop-daemon error by adding sudo to the commands but it still doesn't work in my code. I am calling this code when a submit button is pressed.

Comment: Does the running PHP user have execute permission on `/apps/video/vsss`?

Comment: As stated above I performed a 'sudo chmod a+rwx /apps/video/vsss'. Are you suggesting that I still need to add specific users? and if so how would I determine the user the PHP code would use? It seems like this would be case, where it just doesn't have execute permissions

Comment: What's your indicator that it's not running? What _is_ happening?

Comment: Upon running the script a program that outputs video feed will restart with new settings, to make it easy to tell I disable video output in the new settings. So if it were to execute, I would no longer see video

Comment: Who is the user running the video process? I'd bet it's not the same as the user running the command.

Comment: The user running the process would be root and I'd make that same wager, but could you re-read my first comment at answer the questions?

Comment: My point wasn't that the user running it doesn't have execute permissions (since you believe that it does), rather that the user executing the video command isn't the one with the video player running. If you're logged in as a user on a desktop, something that another service user runs doesn't necessarily happen on _your_ desktop. If that makes sense.

Comment: So you're suggesting that a user still doesn't have execute permissions, and you think that user is the whatever runs the PHP code?

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it seems I was mistaken in the origin of the problem. The bash script was being executed but the start-stop-daemon appears to be not working within it.

Comment: @ColinMorelli well that problem is now fixed and I have edited my question to reflect that, do you have any idea why this might not execute properly?

Comment: @xsdf Have you tried `exec()` or `passthru()` or `system()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lay with a call to a binary file in the vsss script that could only be run as root. We did not want to allow access to that binary file to just anyone.  The solution we came up with involves calling chmod +s on the vsss script which allows permissions for user and group IDs but keeps its owner permissions. We then added the PHP user, which was www-data, to the sudoers file using the NOPASSWD parameter. In my PHP code I then used the line:

```
exec('sudo /apps/video/vsss restart >/dev/null 2>&1 &')
```

The `shell_exec()`/backticks would not work with this method.

Answer (score 0):

use additional parameters, especially output:
exec($command,$output);
var_dump($output);
to determine what can be wrong with your command. If it doesn't work, please show us your code where you use your exec's.

Comment: I have tried, without redirecting the output of course, and the output variable is null.

Comment: I ended up having to write to a file because the code is only executed  in a submit button, making it more difficult to read output. But that was actually output.